# System of ODE with initial values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm very bewildered by the following task in differential equations. We have

$$x'' = -x -z +e^{-t} \\ z' = -2z-2x +3e^{-t}$$
and need to find solutions satisfying $x(0)=0,\ x'(0)=0,\ z(0)=1$. But the problem is, when I transform the above system I get $$z' - 2x'' = e^{-t} \Rightarrow z - 2x' = -e^{-t} \Rightarrow z = 2x' -e^{-t} $$ so when the assumptions are met $z(0) \neq 1$ ! It's so frustrating, what am I missing? FYI I calculated the result and got $x=(-t^2+D_1)e^{-t} + (2t+D_2)te^{-t},\\z=(2t^2+4t+2D_2-2D_1-1)e^{-t} - (4t+2D_2)te^{-t},\\ D_1,D_2\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You forgot to add a constant when integrating : $z' - 2x'' = e^{-t} \Rightarrow z - 2x' = -e^{-t} + D_1 \Rightarrow z = 2x' -e^{-t} + D_1 t + D_2$

Comment: Aaaaaaa, you're right...

Comment: Glad to be of use :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z^\prime-2x^{\prime\prime}=e^{-t}\Rightarrow z-2x^\prime=-e^{-t}+c$, where $c$ denotes a constant.